# Issues with installing Ubuntu which is giving ACPI partion firmare bug

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, acpi

Im trying to install dual booting of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04. Windows 10 is already installed. 
When I boot into the UBUNTU usb, This error pops up and the pc switches off. Boot version is the updated one. Boot mode is UEFI.

> [    7.564526] tmp_crb MFST0101:00: [Firmware Bug]: ACPI region does
>   not cover the entire command/response buffer. [mem
>   0xfed40000-0xfed4087f flags 0x200] vs fed40080 f80

Laptop - MSI GP62 7RD Leopard 
Currently running on Windows 10.

Comment: Have you allocated an un-partitioned space for Ubuntu installation?

Comment: Yes already 38 gb unallocated partition is allocated. but the fact that I cant even boot using a live boot usb shows it has nothing to do with the drives.

Comment: And Boot priority is set to usb drive?